# Браузер Chrome все время выкидывает окно

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, google-chrome, mvc

Пишу сайт. В `side-bar` щелкаем, например, Города и страны (любой раскрывающийся аккордеон) -- в разметке он выглядит так--  `<p data-id="@item.id" class="InfoRender" onclick="window.location.href = '/home/TourInfo?id=@item.id'; return false;">@item.Text</p>`

Так вот -- у меня на локальном сервере редиректится как надо все. А вот когда на хостинг выложил, то в хроме вылетает попап окно с предложением подтвердить действие на aira-tour.ru. Как это можно побороть? Спасибо.

Comment: gcoder!Спасибо друг!Вы гениальный человек! И самое главное вопрос был задан очень непонятно, вы все поняли и указали прямо в корень проблемы!!! СПАСИБО!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну так при ошибке на сервере вы сами вызываете alert("server error"); в $('.InfoRender').live('click',